# Specifying minor grid lines/some dashed grid lines on discrete x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a figure for publication and the graphing convention in my field is non-standard for this information (plotting audiograms).

Some sample data:

```
subsetAudio <- 
structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), Frequency = c(250, 250, 250, 500, 500, 500, 750, 
750, 750, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1500, 1500, 1500, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
3000, 3000, 3000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 6000, 6000, 6000, 8000, 8000, 
8000, 250, 250, 250, 500, 500, 500, 750, 750, 750, 1000, 1000, 
1000, 1500, 1500, 1500, 2000, 2000, 2000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 4000, 
4000, 4000, 6000, 6000, 6000, 8000, 8000, 8000), Ear = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Left", 
"Right"), class = "factor"), dBHL = c(10L, 30L, 20L, 10L, 45L, 
20L, 25L, 50L, 20L, 30L, 45L, 25L, 45L, 45L, 60L, 50L, 45L, 60L, 
55L, 45L, 60L, 60L, 50L, 60L, 65L, 70L, 65L, 65L, 75L, 70L, 30L, 
35L, 25L, 10L, 45L, 25L, 30L, 50L, 25L, 30L, 50L, 30L, 40L, 45L, 
45L, 50L, 55L, 60L, 60L, 55L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 65L, 65L, 75L, 60L, 
65L, 85L, 65L)), .Names = c("Subject", "Frequency", "Ear", "dBHL"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 71L, 72L, 
73L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 111L, 112L, 
113L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 151L, 
152L, 153L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 
191L, 192L, 193L), class = "data.frame")
```

What makes this difficult is that "Frequency" has to be entered as a factor, on a discrete x scale, because of the spacing of the values.

With all discrete points labelled:

```
ggplot(subsetAudio, aes(x = factor(Frequency), y = dBHL, group = Subject)) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(~ Ear) + 
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed",size=0.8) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Frequency (kHz)",labels=c("0.25", "0.5", "0.75", "1", "1.5", "2", "3", "4", "6", "8"), position = "top") +
    scale_y_reverse(name = "Level (dB HL)", lim=c(120,-10),minor_breaks = seq(0 ,120, 5), breaks = seq(-10, 120, 10)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "black",size=0.1)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "black",linetype="dashed",size=0.1)) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank()) + 
  geom_text(data=data.frame(x = 1.5, y = -6.25, label=c("a)", "b)"), 
                            Ear=c("Left","Right")), aes(x,y,label=label), size=8,inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

This produces the following figure:
[image]

The problem here is that I need the x scale grid lines at 0.75, 1.5, 3, and 6 to be dashed.

I tried just plotting the "major" grid lines (.25, 5, 1, 2, 4, 8):

```
ggplot(subsetAudio, aes(x = factor(Frequency), y = dBHL, group = Subject)) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(~ Ear) + 
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed",size=0.8) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Frequency (kHz)",breaks=c("250","500","1000","2000","4000","8000"),labels=c("0.25", "0.5", "1", "2", "4", "8"), position = "top") +
  scale_y_reverse(name = "Level (dB HL)", lim=c(120,-10),minor_breaks = seq(0 ,120, 5), breaks = seq(-10, 120, 10)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "black",size=0.1)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "black",linetype="dashed",size=0.1)) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank()) + 
  geom_text(data=data.frame(x = 1.5, y = -6.25, label=c("a)", "b)"), 
                            Ear=c("Left","Right")), aes(x,y,label=label), size=8,inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

Which gives this plot:
[image]

But, I can't figure out how to add in dashed lines at the missing points (0.75, 1.5, 3, and 6)

Any suggestion as to how I can work around this?

In the end, I need a mix of solid and dashed lines on the x axis:

```
0.25 - solid
0.5 - solid
0.75 - dashed
1 - solid
1.5 - dashed
2 - solid
3 - dashed
4 - solid
6 - dashed
8 - solid
```

Comment: Did you post all your data? I'm getting different plots from what you posted.

Comment: Whoops sorry about the misinterpretation - `scale_x_discrete` doesn't have a minor breaks argument so you might have to do something hacky

Comment: @MikeH. Updated post with complete data
The lack of a minor breaks argument is my roadblock. I'm hoping someone can suggest a hacky workaround :)

Answer (score 3):

I made some hacky progress by turning the "Frequency" variable into a continuous variable:

```
subsetAudio$Frequency <- as.numeric(mapvalues(Avg_Audio$Frequency, c("250","500","750","1000","1500","2000","3000","4000","6000","8000"), 
                                     c("1","2","2.5","3","3.5","4","4.5","5","5.5","6")))
```

Then playing with major and minor grid line:

```
ggplot(Audios, aes(x = Frequency, y = dBHL, group = Subject)) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(~ Ear) + 
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed",size=0.8) +
  geom_line(data = Avg_Audio, aes(Frequency,dBHL, group = Subject), size = 1.5) + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Frequency (kHz)",breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),labels=c("0.25", "0.5", "1", "2", "4", "8"),minor_breaks=c(2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5), position = "top") +
  scale_y_reverse(name = "Level (dB HL)", lim=c(120,-20),minor_breaks = seq(0 ,120, 10), breaks = seq(-20, 120, 20)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "black",size=0.1), panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(colour="grey", linetype="dashed"),
        strip.text.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(data=data.frame(x = 1.5, y = -10, label=c("a)", "b)"), 
            Ear=c("Left","Right")),
            aes(x,y,label=label), size=8,inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

This produces the following figure:[image]

This is very close....but I cannot find a way to add ticks or labels to the minor (dashed) grid lines (0.75, 1.5, 3, 6).

Any suggestions?